# @WebMvcTest equivalents annotation for Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I am looking for a feature that is similar to what `@WebMvcTest` does.

What `@WebMvcTest` does .
1. `only instantiating the web layer, not the whole context`
2. Only works with `Spring Boot` application (as it is in the package - org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest).

What I want to achieve

Write unit test case on Controller only instantiating the web layer, not the whole context on Spring MVC application (not Spring Boot application)?

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What's wrong with using @WebMvcTest?

Comment: Nothing wrong using `@WebMvcTest` but it only works in Spring Boot application.
I am in a situation where `XML configuration` is in placed and looking for similar alternative. Hope this explains.